# Unable to install h5py on Ubuntu 14.04 with icc compiler

Tags: python-3.x, installation, ubuntu-14.04, icc, h5py

I am trying to install netcdf4 package on Ubuntu 14.04 using the following command

**pip3 install netcdf4**

This did install successfully but when I try to execute a script which had import netCDF4 I get the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "display.py", line 5, in <module>
from netCDF4 import Dataset  # http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/netCDF4/__init__.py", line 3, in <module> from ._netCDF4 import *
File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 942, in init netCDF4._netCDF4 (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:76006)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/netcdftime/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .netcdftime import utime, JulianDayFromDate, DateFromJulianDay
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/netcdftime/netcdftime.py",   line 14, in <module>
from ._datetime import datetime 
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/netcdftime/_datetime.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: __intel_sse2_strchr
```

So it looks like this has a dependency on cython and hdf5. 
 I did install cython and that did install successfully.

When I do a pip3 install h5py I get the following errors -

Any suggestions ? I am using Intel icc compiler and cannot switch to gcc.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/setup.py", line 149, in <module>

cmdclass = CMDCLASS,

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

dist.run_commands()

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands

self.run_command(cmd)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

cmd_obj.run()

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 53, in run

return _install.run(self)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/install.py", line 583, in run

self.run_command('build')

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

self.distribution.run_command(command)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

cmd_obj.run()

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run

self.run_command(cmd_name)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

self.distribution.run_command(command)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command

cmd_obj.run()

File "/tmp/pip_build_root/h5py/setup_build.py", line 147, in run

from Cython.Build import cythonize

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Cython/Build/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

from .Dependencies import cythonize

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 50, in <module>

from ..Compiler.Main import Context, CompilationOptions, default_options

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 28, in <module>

from .Scanning import PyrexScanner, FileSourceDescriptor

 ImportError/usr/local/lib/python3.4/distpackages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.cpython-34m.so: undefined symbol: __intel_sse2_strchr
```

Comment: You have to use a python compiled with icc.    You're using a gcc-compiled version.  Recompile python, reinstall modules /w pip.

Comment: @BadZen - python is compiled with icc. However how can I check what is python compiled with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially:

```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install build-essential  # that should get you the right gcc
  sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
  sudo apt-get install python3-dev
  sudo apt-get install python3-lxml
```

Then install pip3 throught apt-get - verify your pip is consistent with Ubuntu:

```
 apt-get install python-pip3
 apt-get install python3-h5py
```

And then any other modules

Comment: @dmityro - I cannot use gcc. All my programs are compiled with icc. I cannot change now

Comment: This looks like your situation http://bryanwweber.com/writing/personal/2014/01/11/installing-numpy-scipy-on-ubuntu-12.04.3-from-scratch-source-with-intel-compilers/